# Как отправить текст в форму ввода сайта для python?

Tags: html, python, urllib

Я хочу ввести данные в формы textarea или form. Как это сделать (желательно используя библиотеку urllib) ?

Все значения атрибутов этих тегов известны (для form также знаю значения тега input).

Comment: Смотреть, какой POST-запрос отправляется (через инструменты разработчика в браузере, например) и пытаться повторить такой же с urllib

Comment: Как именно его повторить? Я немного чайник

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала надо научится гуглить. 5 секунд и готово.
http://python-lab.blogspot.com/2012/06/python-101_09.html